# Convert different date strings to unix timestamp in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two strings. How can I convert them to UNIX timestamp (eg.: "1284101485")? (Please observe that 1284101485 is not the correct answer for this case.)

I don't care about time zones as long as it is consistent.

```
string_1_to_convert = 'Tue Jun 25 13:53:58 CEST 2019'   
string_2_to_convert = '2019-06-25 13:53:58'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Install:

```
$ pip install dateparser
```

Sample code:

```
import dateparser
from time import mktime

string_1_to_convert = 'Tue Jun 25 13:53:58 CEST 2019'
string_2_to_convert = '2019-06-25 13:53:58'

datetime1 = dateparser.parse(string_1_to_convert)
datetime2 = dateparser.parse(string_2_to_convert)

unix_secs_1 = mktime(datetime1.timetuple())
unix_secs_2 = mktime(datetime2.timetuple())

print(unix_secs_1)
print(unix_secs_2)
```

Output:

```
1561492438.0
1561488838.0
```

The above implementation gives you a consistent response and doesn't give you an error when trying to parse `CEST`.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to parse by a format you specify.

try this:

```py
import datetime

string_1_to_convert = 'Tue Jun 25 13:53:58 CEST 2019'
string_2_to_convert = '2019-06-25 13:53:58'

ts1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_1_to_convert, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y").timestamp()
ts2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_2_to_convert, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp()

print(ts1)
print(ts2)
```

**NOTICE:** the `CEST` part might be non-portable, as strptime only knows how to parse timezones that appear in `time.tzname`.

Comment: I guess this would work if I first remove CEST. However I accepted the solution by Bilesh Ganguly which doesn't require that. Thank you.